# For dynamically created forms, is ASP.NET MVC 2 worth the learning curve?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, asp.net-mvc-2

I have to create a web application that allows you to create specific XML documents. To generate a document, the user must be able to ...

- fill out fields that will be the XML content, using dropdown lists, text input fields, calendar controls ... Some fields will be validated.
- use some default values (text, new GUID, current date ...)
- add or remove sub nodes. The minimum an maximum number of nodes will be validated.

All fields, relations and validations should be configurable by using config files.

I have an idea of how to implement this in a homebrew MVP or MVVM pattern way. Now I wonder if MVC 2 can help me enough to justify the learning curve. (MVC 3 is not an option, as my client still uses VS2008.) In two weeks I should have a working application. It is for internal "power user" use, so it doesn't have to look too fancy, but the main concept and functionality should be waterproof.

My background: I have many years of experience with Win Forms developement and basic knowledge of ASP.NET (did some smaller apps with it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ASP.NET MVC* is very different from *ASP.NET WebForms*.

*ASP.NET WebForms* is aimed for rapid, "drag-and-drop" development. In some way, it tries to recreate the way you develop *Windows Forms* applications. This can be cool, but sometimes beginners get trapped by that similarity and forget that they are developing a web server application, trying to make things in a way which is improper in that context, finally realising that they have to learn a lot about and to deal with *WebForms*-specific intrinsics like page life cycles, *PostBacks*, *ViewStates*, etc. (let those who didn't struggle with one of those cast the first downvote).

On the other hand, *ASP.NET MVC* is a much more flexible framework, and as such requires from you more discipline to get it right. it also requires from you to have a good understanding of engineering principles like *REST* and *Model-View-Controller*. The good thing is that there are (almost) no surprises because you are in control of (almost) everything.

Personally speaking, I developed *WebForms* applications for several years, and it took some time to master it. As for *ASP.NET MVC*, it took me about 2 days to **[learn about the core concepts](http://www.asp.net/mvc)**, watch the great **[NerdDinner](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/creating-nerddinnercom-with-microsoft-aspnet-model-view-controller-mvc)** tutorial, test and play with code, until I felt completely comfortable with that technology.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just wonder: If I create all controls programatically, do I benefit of the MVC framework? My fear is that MVC is mainly template/designer (perhaps also inline code) oriented. What do you think: Can I only -- and quickly -- use some convieniences of the MVC framework?

Comment: @Daniel: in some way, MVC *requires* you to create your controls "programmatically" - you are not going to use WebForms server-side controls. Usually you would use HTML-generating server-side helpers (this is currently the standard way to generate controls in *AS.NET MVC*). For your calendar and treeview controls, you could find a plethora of [JQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/) which, with a few JS code lines, would "transform" your generated HTML code into something very appealing.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly if you have only a basic knowledge of ASP.NET, learning ASP.NET MVC in two weeks and developing an application according to those requirements could be a challenging task. Of course that's only my personal point of view and it is subjective.

Comment: disagree: like Maxim says, ASP.NET MVC is very different from ASP.NET WebForms. More experience in ASP.NET WebForms will hardly help better understand the concepts of ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @chiccodoro, absolutely disagree with you. ASP.NET MVC is based on ASP.NET and if you are not familiar with how ASP.NET works (basic things like HttpContext, Request, Response, Session, Cookies, Cache, Http modules, web.config, Membership, authentication, ... you will have hard time understanding ASP.NET MVC). Personally I always recommend people first learning ASP.NET (not going into the details but basic notions are absolutely fundamental).

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. People usually refer to *ASP.NET* (execution platform / framework required to run *ASP.NET MVC* / *Web Forms* / mixed tech. web sites) when talking about *ASP.NET Web Forms*, certainly for historical reasons.

Comment: You write that "basic notions are absolutely fundamental". Hey, I wrote that I have "basic knowledge of ASP.NET". I mean, I know "HttpContext, Request, Response, Session, Cookies, Cache" and used them in several scenarios. I also have been a PHP developer for some years, so "how the web works" is not the question for me. Perhaps my understanding of professional development pushed me to understate my experience.